# Rails 4 - Customizing (json) format of response objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a Rails Controller who responds with JSON objects. Let's take this theoretical example :

```
respond_to :json
def index 
  respond_with Comment.all
end
```

This would respond with something like

```
[{"id":1,"comment_text":"Random text ", "user_id":1  ,"created_at":"2013-07-26T15:08:01.271Z","updated_at":"2013-07-26T15:08:01.271Z"}]
```

What i'm looking for is a "best practice" method to interfere with the formating of the json object and return something like this :

```
[{"id":1,"comment_text":"Random text ", "username": "John Doe", "user_id":1  ,"created_at":"3 hours ago"}]
```

As you can see, i'm adding a column that doesn't exist in the database model "username" , i'm taking out "updated_at" , and i'm formatting "created_at" to contain human readable text rather than a date.

Any thoughts anyone ?

Comment: Your best bet is to jbuilder: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder It's included in Rails 4 by default.

Answer (score 12):

Overwriting `as_json` or working with JSON ERB views can be cumbersome, that's why I prefer using ActiveModel Serializers (or RABL):

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  attributes :id, :created_at

  def created_at
    time_ago_in_words(object.created_at)
  end

end
```

Look here for more information:

1. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers
2. https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

Answer (score 4):

2 ways:

first: define a view, where you build and return an hash that you'll convert to json.

controller:

```
YourController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end
end
```

view: index.json.erb

```
res = {
  :comments => @comments.map do |x|
    item_attrs = x.attributes
    item_attrs["username"] = calculate_username
  end
}

res.to_json.html_safe
```

second: use gem [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)

Answer (score 3):

I'd redefine the `as_json` method of your model.

In your Comment model,

```
def username
  "John Doe"
end

def time_ago
  "3 hours ago"
end

def as_json(options={})
  super(:methods => [:username, :time_ago], except: [:created_at, :updated_at])
end
```

You don't have to change your controller

Take a look at the documentation for [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: use the to_json method and pass the options you want, simple easy and flexible. You can easily use different actions to pass more or less attributes from your model. All the detail is in the documentation linked to above